# PHP Create Tar File: PharData [PharException] "contents of file could not be written, seek failed"

Tags: php, tar, phar

I'm trying to create a tar file using PHP and I'm running into issues.

Using class PharData, `::addFile` and `::buildFromDirectory` both throw the same exception:

> exception 'PharException' with message 'tar-based phar
>   "C:/Apache24/htdocs/_frames/storage/glacier/archive_cache/9.tar"
>   cannot be created, contents of file "MVI_4492.MOV" could not be
>   written, seek failed' in
>   C:/Apache24/htdocs/_frames/storage/glacier/cron/upload_archives.php:212
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:/Apache24/htdocs/_frames/storage/glacier/cron/upload_archives.php(212):
>   PharData->addFile('C://Apache24//htd...', 'MVI_4492.MOV') #1 {main}

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of disk space, during operation. After it - space is restored (because tmp files are filled with data and then cleaned).

If not, then another reason is that you are using 32bit php, which does not support files larger than 2GB

Comment: 64 bit PHP. Running out of tmp space. If you have any ideas as to how to _not_ run out of tmp space, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Do not use PharData class....alternative? use orginal tar(.exe), and run it from the OS, through php exec(). There is no tmp file issue AND it runs about 8x faster! (on my PC)

Comment: Tried that on both the Windows server and a CentOS server. Files less than around 10GB work but more than that it runs out of space and fails. Files are as large as 200GB+.

Comment: I have just tested on Windows 7, gnu4win version of tar, and 20GB tar file was created without any problems...